Changed project from QGIS 3.16 to 3.24, now 'NULL' fields turn into '-9223372036854775808'
Been working on a digitizing project on QGIS 3.16.15-Hannover, as I like to use LTR versions for the stability.
But, 3.34 introduced an automatically incrementing UUID field, which I find useful.
My digitizing workflow in finding the correct street width within the map relies on guide lines which have the width field value as NULL. When I have the suitable width, ie. the distance between the guides, I find the centreline, and give that a width in meters so it matches the raster map.
These are styled with different rules, so I can turn each one on or off.
The issue I have is that now when I draw a vector line in 3.34, it no longer gets the value NULL on default, but instead -9223372036854775808, which will render every new line invisible with the current symbology rules.
Trying to erase the value manually does not help, it stays firmly at that number.
So how come does the value change to such a weird number, and not stay as NULL?
The project and layer CRS is EPSG:2392 - KKJ / Finland zone 2 if that's a clue.

Is that PostGIS layer or what?

@user30184 ESRI Shapefile. Project is a scanned, georeferenced raster map and shapefile vectors, and some WMS layers for reference.

If feels like some sort of bug. Shapefile does not support null values directly, but the specification defines "Any floating point number smaller than –10^38 is considered by a shapefile reader to represent a "no data" value." -9223372036854775808 is bigger than –10^38, so not "no data". Have you tried to use GeoPackage instead of shapefile?

Exporting the layer as GeoPackage in 3.16 and opening in 3.34 did not change anything, new lines still get that same value instead of NULL.

Please create new simple layer that shows the issue and share the procedure so that others can try to re-produce.
